# Update elements inside an externally loaded webview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, webview

**Update**
I found 'webview.executeScript' however, I can't access any of the custom functions.

This is a major step forward though. Any suggestions welcome.

**Original post**

We developed a Kiosk Web Extension for Chrome OS that loads an externally hosted webpage. The page is loaded into a **webview**. This page display dynamic information that gets updated daily. In order to push "manual" updates out to the page, we maintain an open WebSocket connection to the Kiosk app. This allows us to refresh the page, update the page, push information, etc. However, we need to access either the javascript loaded inside the webview or we need to access the elements. I'm not sure if I'm explaining this right, or if it is possible to do what I am asking.

Right now we are opening two connections to the websocket server. One is from the webpage and the other is from the extension. The goal is to cut down to one connection.

I added pseudo code to give an idea of what is I need to do.

**Chrome Web Extension Kiosk index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">

        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Kiosk example background js** 
(note: I know this wouldn't be doable via jquery)

```
document.onLoad({ 
    $("#page").html('<webview id="browser" src="example.com"></webview>');
});

function ReceiveWebSocketMessage(msg) {
    switch (msg.cmd) {
        case "updatedate":
            $("browser").UpdateDate(msg.data);
        break;

        case "reboot":
            chrome.runtime.RebootDevice();
            break;
    }
}
```

**Webpage example.com**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="datetime">
            1/1/2016
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Webpage example JS http://example.com/app.js**

```
function UpdateDate(newdate) {
    $("#datetime").html = newdate;
}
```

I threw together a quick diagram of what the old design is like and what the new design is.

To sum it up, I need to access functions that are on the external page. I've not had luck trying to accomplish it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I found the following examples:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/shared-script

Basically I added this to my code:

```
function Execute(code) {
    var webview = document.querySelector('webview');

    webview.executeScript({
        code: generateScriptText(code)
    });
}

function generateScriptText(fn) {
    var fnText = fn.toString()
        .replace(/"/g, '\\"') // Escape double-quotes.
        .replace(/(\r?\n|\r)/g, '\\n'); // Insert newlines correctly.

    var scriptText =
        '(function() {\n' +
        '  var script = document.createElement("script");\n' +
        '  script.innerHTML = "(function() { (' + fnText + ')(); })()" \n' +
        '  document.body.appendChild(script);\n' +
        '})()';
    return scriptText;
}
```